# why do i get an error when running my program: "dates is not defined," when dates is defined in an external js library?

Tags: javascript, variables, shared-libraries, undefined

I am coding a program with a dropdown menu i imported from a library. my objective is to obtain the day and month and use it to compute the zodiac sign. later, i will have an array of random horoscopes and that will be displayed as well. however, after i execute my code, i get an error: "dates is not defined." how can i reference the date and month from the dropdown menu correctly?

```
var astro_sign

function getzodiac() {

var day = parseInt(document.getElementsByClassName('bear-dates').value);
var month = document.getElementsByClassName('bear-months').value;
var year = document.getElementsByClassName('bear-years').value;

 if (month == "December"){ 

        if (day < 22) 
        astro_sign = "Sagittarius"; 
        else
        astro_sign ="Capricorn"; 
    }
```

and then I want it to print an output:

```
document.getElementById("zodiac").innerHTML="You were born under the sign of" + " "+astro_sign+"!"
```

here is my body:

```
<h5 id="zodiac"> </h5> 
<button class="button" onclick="getzodiac()">get my zodiac!</button>
```

This is how dates is defined in the library js file:

```
function dates(tags)
{

    if(tags == '')
    //If the dates('') paramenter is empty, add no tags
    {
        var dates = "";
        var i;
        for (i = 1; i < 32;  i++ )
        {
            dates += i;
        }
    }
    else
    //If the dates('option') has paramenter, add the tags to it
    {
        var dates = "";
        var i;
        for (i = 1; i < 32;  i++ )
        {
            dates += "<" + tags +">" + i +"</" + tags +">";
        }   
    }
```

Comment: can u comment the line where the error occurs?

Comment: Can you post full source code? looks like a ordering issue make sure javascript is at the bottom of html

Comment: @Viney I suspect that datas() is not defined 'couse 'export' miss

Comment: @canerandagio I don't have a line where the error occurs. chrome's console doesn't give me an error, and I only knew it was the dates because I put it into a playcode: https://playcode.io/591948/

Comment: @Viney I'm pretty sure my javascript is after my HTML. Would I post the full code in a code box or link to it?

Answer (score 0):

In the code inserted in HTML, you have a reference to dates() function which is declared in the calendar.js file but you have not exported it using 'export' keyword. [MDN export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)

```
export dates(){
    //some code
}
```

next you can import it in HTML code script

```
import dates from './calendar.js'
```

now you can use the function dates() in your code.
the same goes for the other functions declared in calendar.js, months() and years()

Comment: where do i place the export and imports? directly in the javascript part? can I export and import dates, month, and year in one line?

Comment: Follow my example, use export before the declaration of the function in clendar.js and import on top of javascript code of the html file. I suggest to read MDN documentation. Can u upvote my reply please? Thanks